# Finding the right place to insert in a circular, doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I want to insert the names of some people into a circular, doubly linked list in alphabetical order, but I can only add up to three, and I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm passing the new node to be inserted to an `insert` function, creating a pointer to it, and looping through the entire list in order to find the correct insertion spot. However, when it gets to more than three names, a node gets deleted and another inserted. Could someone help me figure this out?

Other Details:

- Each `Node` has two pointers called `next` and `prev` and a `string` called `data` as data members
- The `List` class contains insert and display functions, and a head pointer which points to a dummy head node. This head node's `next` and `prev` pointers point to itself when the `List` is initialized

This is the insert function that I've written:

```
void List::insert(Node newObject)
{


    Node *toInsert = &newObject;
    Node *cur = head->next;

    while((cur != head) && (newObject.data > cur->data))
    {
            cout << "Is this loop entered?" << endl;
            cur = cur->next;

    }

    toInsert->next = cur;
    toInsert->prev = cur->prev;

    cur->prev = toInsert;
    toInsert->prev->next = toInsert;        

}
```

And my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "list.h"
#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    Node nikhil = Node("Nikhil");
    Node kaustubh = Node("Kaustubh");
    Node jon = Node("Jonathan");
    Node james = Node("James");
    Node elias = Node("Elias");
    Node kenny = Node("Kenny");

    List suiteMates;

    suiteMates.insert(nikhil);
    suiteMates.insert(kaustubh);
    suiteMates.insert(jon);
    suiteMates.insert(james);
    suiteMates.insert(elias);
    suiteMates.insert(kenny);

    suiteMates.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert` function inserts a local variable, which goes out of scope when control passes out of the function. Later you try to dereference pointers to that vanished object, which is **Undefined Behavior**.